# Is there a way to set a mark like in Emacs?

Tags: notepad++

Emacs has the concept of point and mark.  The **point** is where you are now and the **mark** is some spot you set in the text.  This is useful when, for example, you want to make a macro that does this:

```
Set a mark
Search forward looking for the first occurrence of a string
(Now everything from the mark to the point is selected)
Delete (the selected region)
```

I'm trying to do something similar in NPP, but I can't see how.

Failing that, how can you highlight something when you can't just hold the shift key because that would prevent you from running the next command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit menu has a "Begin/End select" command that can be used to select large areas. The command is also available in the right-click context menu. (Just checked on Notepad++ 5.5.4.)